# Change Windows 10 Font and Zoom Settings

Tags: .net, powershell, fonts, size, windows-10-desktop

Our team is distributing Windows 10 that has some features locked down, but for which we provide some automation, one of which is changing screen resolutions. I have been asked to add the ability to change the **Display** settings, **Make text bigger** and **Make everything bigger**.

The only solution I have come across requires rewriting the registry key, and then logging off and then back on. Also, the only solution that I have seen is with PowerShell or CMD. I am currently working with .NET

My questions then are:

- Is there a better way? The registry change is easy enough, but I would rather not force the users to log off.
- Regardless, I'd rather do this in .NET, so wondering if could someone point me to an existing code sample, or provide one.

Example 1

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v LogPixels /t reg_dword /d 144
exit /b
```

Example 2

```
cd 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name LogPixels -Value 144
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name Win8DpiScaling -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name FocusBorderHeight -Value 2
Set-ItemProperty -Path . -Name FocusBorderWidth -Value 2
Write-Host 'Sign out and sign back in again to see changes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested with your settings changes, but you could try the function below

```
function Refresh-Explorer {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    $code = @'
private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff); 
private const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a; 
private const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002; 

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout ( IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult ); 

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")] 
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

public static void Refresh() {
    SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, null, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 3000, IntPtr.Zero); 
}
'@

    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Namespace MyWinAPI -Name Explorer 
    [MyWinAPI.Explorer]::Refresh()
}
```

Comment: This would be paired with the settings changes to update windows explorer? What have you used this with?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I've tried it both as in code, as well as the fuller code sample as a PowerShell script. will keep looking/trying...